# Why we should use {} in return statment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and I have question:

Why I should use curly braces inside return statement?

Example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Hobbies from './Hobbies';

const HobbyList = () => {

    const hobbies = ["Surfing", "Rock climbing", "Mountain biking", "Breakdancing"];
    return (
        <div>
           { hobbies.map(hob => <Hobbies hobbies={hob}/>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default HobbyList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the code needs to be separated from `HTML` tags and this is the way how you can run `JavaScript` code inside your `return` statement.

As the documentation states:

> It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. We recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look like. JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the full power of JavaScript.

Suggested documentation to read:

1. [Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)
2. [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In React, curly braces are used to embed JavaScript inside JSX (JavaScript Syntax Extension). Inside your `<div></div>` tags, without the curly braces, it would just be a bunch of text, a string.

You can find out more about this in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the return function in react you can only write JSX or simple string. To use variables or state declared in your react component you use curly braces `{}` for that. This is identical to what template languages like ejs use.

Like in your component if you write without curly braces it would just show whatever you have written literally on screen.

TLDR- curly braces are used for Embedding Expressions in JSX. You can learn more about it here - https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 1):

You **should** use curly braces if you want your compiler to treat the code sample as an **expression**, not as a **text**.

If you wouldn't use curly braces here, it would basically render it as a string, until a JSX element is found - in your particular case - only `<Hobbies hobbies={hob}/>` would be rendered as a component. The rest would be just a static text.